# Is this a Canvas's lineWidth bug?

Tags: html, canvas, svg

try this link http://jsfiddle.net/4pE9S/ firstly.You will find out that the lineWidth don't work. Some of Lines are  thinness,but must of them look like 2pixel not 1 pixe. How to solve this .
I know this is solution for SVG using shape-rendering="optimizeSpeed".Is there a solution for Canvas.
thanks

Comment: It works for me... What browser are you using?

Comment: Do you check it careful?I use almost browsers.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug. See the Q&A here:

> Q: Why did you start x and y at 0.5? Why not 0?

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/canvas.html#paths

If you draw a line from 0,10 to 10,10, you are drawing between pixels and it will look thicker

If you draw a line from 0.5,10.5 to 10.5,10.5 you are drawing on the pixel and it will look "perfect"

Comment: Hi,Simon Sarris. I know this solution. But It is very hard to move every line with 0.5 pixel. At the same time,I change the lineWidth to 2 pixel. I find all of them don't look like same http://jsfiddle.net/CkWgq/. also some thicker,some not. How bad it . When I use SVG ,C++ JAVA ,flash. All of them don't have this problem.

Comment: Hi,Simon Sarris. thanks. But it can't work in any time. Because all of my lines will look like ( from 10.003 100.3 to 101.0011 122.222 ) . It can't be always *.5 .

Comment: I usually place `ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5)` at the top of my code, and everything will move along. Would this be a feasible solution?

Comment: ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5) don't work. Because my lines' from and to are not always integer .thanks also

Comment: Javas, the code example I sent you will always have the numbers end in 0.5 because I use x|0 on the number first, which is similar to doing Math.floor(). Take a look at the code.

Comment: Hi,Simon Sarris .Because all of my lines will look like ( from 10.003 100.3 to 101.0011 122.222 ) . It can't be always *.5 . It will be very precise .